# Count distinct prefixes

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column called `tape_name` in the table `tapes`.
I'd like to construct a select statement where all distinct prefixes are being counted, i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(TAPE_NAME) 
  FROM TAPES 
  WHERE TAPE_NAME LIKE DISTINCT SUBSTRING(TAPE_NAME,1,3)
```

If these are rows of the tape_name column:

```
DBZ000
DBZ001
AGT546
AGT432
```

Then I want it to produce:

```
DBZ  2
AGT  2
```

If the solution could be applicable for DB2, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select substr(TAPE_NAME,1,3), count(*)
from tapes 
group by substr(TAPE_NAME,1,3)
```

Comment: By coincidence, I did same thing earlier today, examining table name prefixes.